# How does the Time Stop spell interact with the duration of a previously cast Bless spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, time, duration

When someone casts [*time stop*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/time-stop) (in this case an [Archmage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/archmage)), they take turns while everyone else is stopped in time:

> You briefly stop the flow of time for everyone but yourself. No time passes for other creatures, while you take 1d4 + 1 turns in a row

Suppose that a [*bless*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bless) spell was already in effect when the Archmage used *time stop*. The *bless* spell usually lasts for 1 minute (or 10 rounds). Would the extra turns from *time stop* count towards the duration of the *bless* spell?

I am assuming (possibly wrongly) that the answer may depend on who cast the *bless* spell and who are the targets. The main point that I want to know is what factors, if any, are used to determine whether the spell's duration is affected. I have considered this (non-exhaustive) list of factors:

1. Whether the spell was cast by the Archmage (assuming he has the ability to cast the spell) or someone else.
2. Whether it is affecting only the Archmage, only other characters or both.

So which of these (or other) factors are used to determine whether the extra turns one takes during *time stop* would affect the duration of the *bless* spell?

Comment: This question has been discussed in this meta: [How should I split/improve this question so it is not too broad?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8148/33707)

Comment: Were both Bless and Time Stop spells cast on the same target? Or it was one target blessed and the Time Stop was cast on the Bless caster?

Comment: @enkryptor The question is about all those cases really (as suggested in the meta)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### The *bless* spell is not interrupted

The key to the answer is:

> You briefly stop the flow of time for everyone but yourself.

For everyone else, *delta t* is zero.

> No time passes for other creatures

Turns / rounds each last six seconds -- six seconds elapse from the beginning of someone's turn and the beginning of their next turn.  From this game mechanic, we can say that the usual *delta t* from round to round is six seconds.  Spells with duration of a minute can be modeled as being on a counter in this case: you count down one for each turn/round elapsed.

For everyone who is not the archmage, their time / turn / round counter remains where it was when *time stop* went into effect.  Since no time is passing for them, the durations of their spells are, compared to the archmage's frame of reference, extended.  The archmage's *delta t* keeps moving.  For the other characters, they don't notice a difference since for them time stopped.

#### The *bless* spell's duration depends on the caster

In the case of *bless*, a concentration spell, the duration is keyed to the character who cast it, which is also the character who is concentrating on it.  If it is a character who is not the archmage, their *delta t* is zero so their duration counter resumes on *their* next turn. (That is after *time stop* ends).  Their spell still lasts a minute for them because time (and the counter) stopped for everyone but the archmage.  That would provide the archmage with a few extra rounds / turns of the bless spell's magical effects.

If the archmage cast *bless* (from a ring of spell storing) it's duration would keep decreasing since time/turns are ticking away for the archmage.

@Medix2 asked for clarification in a comment:

> If bless were cast by somebody else, but cast on the Archmage, would they benefit from it?

The answer is: yes.  Nothing in the *time stop* spell says that it stops the effects of other spells.  *Bless*, once it takes effect, keeps on taking effect until the spell ends (or concentration ends).  Nothing in its text says otherwise.

---

> Concentration
> Some spells require *you* to maintain concentration in order to keep their magic active. If *you* lose concentration, such a spell ends. (Basic Rules p. 79)

In plain English, *you* in those two sentences is the caster of a spell requiring concentration.  Unless *you* lose concentration, the spell does not end.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer: Since Time Stop only affects creatures, and with no reference to other spells, the duration any other spells (including bless) would continue to count down while the Time Stop caster would spend their turns.**

> 9th-level transmutation
>
> Casting Time: 1 action
>
> Range: Self
>
> Components: V
>
> Duration: Instantaneous
>
> You briefly stop the flow of time for everyone but yourself. No time
>   passes for other creatures, while you take 1d4 + 1 turns in a row,
>   during which you can use actions and move as normal. This spell ends
>   if one of the actions you use during this period, or any effects that
>   you create during this period, affects a creature other than you or an
>   object being worn or carried by someone other than you.
>
> In addition, the spell ends if you move to a place more than 1,000
>   feet from the location where you cast it.

According to the description of 5th Edition's Time Stop Spell, Time Stop doesn't speed up the caster to be able to perform multiple actions in a reduced amount of time. The spell specifically slows down all creatures it effects so only to their perspective, the caster is moving incredibly fast. This means that to the caster and anyone else outside the influence of Time Stop, time is proceeding at a normal pace. This also means that creatures affected are essentially losing rounds, not turns, as the caster is spending a turn normally, and then the affected creatures just simply don't have the time to make any actions. Keep in mind that the spell ends prematurely, if any creature is affected in any way by the caster during Time Stop's duration.

Also, the spell's description only references creatures. This means that all objects, magical artifacts, ***spells***, and anything that is not a creature, are not affected by Time Stop. This means that they also proceed through time at a normal pace.

This means that any spell that has a duration, continues to count down, and perform normally as the caster takes their 1d4+1 *normal* turns. Keep in mind, that any duration spells cast before Time Stop will continue to affect their zones of influence. Damage spells will continue to damage creatures as well, including the spell caster. And finally if any spells' duration would expire during the spell casters "*bonus*" rounds, then that spell would expire normally, and effected creatures will have to wait until Time Stop ends to notice.

Comment: I'd argue that whether the caster speeds up or not is entirely a matter of perspective. Speed, at least in this case, is relative. If I had to adjudicate an absolute ruling one way or the other, though, I'd have to say speeding up the caster seems more plausible: range is ***self*** and the description says "stop the flow of time for ***everyone*** but yourself" - there's no numerical limit here - it is referencing every other individual anywhere! I know this is a 9th level spell, but that would have been some seriously OP stuff right there!

Answer (score 1):

### No time passes during the Time Stop

Time Stop has a duration of *instantaneous*, during which you take 1d4+1 turns in a row. Mechanically, no *rounds* (or any other forms of time) pass during these turns, for you or for any other creature. Thus, no time is counted against the duration of *Bless* as well as any other spells you have on you, whether you cast them or not.