# Does Time Stop disrupt concentration on spells?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

If I have a wizard that casts [*time stop*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/time-stop), it doesn't actually speed up the caster; rather, it slows every other creature down. That would suggest that the wizard is taking their bonus turns as regular turns, and then the affected creatures just skip out on those rounds until they can act again.

If that's the case, does *time stop* disrupt other spellcaster's spells that have concentration while the wizard is spending their "bonus" turns, and therefore can't spend the bonus action to maintain the concentration?

Comment: Related, probably a dupe: [How does the Time Stop spell interact with the duration of a previously cast Bless spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/127555/)

Comment: @enkryptor I'd argue it is not a duplicate since *bless* may have other considerations that are not immediately apparent to someone already familiar with the game. Also the other question addresses the duration itself as well, not just the Concentration.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maintaining concentration does not require a bonus action, or any other kind of action. There are only 4 conditions that end concentration:

- The spellcaster can choose to end it at any time, no action required
- Casting another spell that requires concentration
- Taking damage and failing the resulting Constitution saving throw
- Being incapacitated or killed

Since *Time Stop* does not cause any of these things to happen, it has no effect on a spellcaster's concentration.

Comment: Technically, the third point is "Failing a Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration after taking damage _or under other circumstances determined by the DM_."

Comment: @Marq Can you site where in the rules *or under other circumstances determined by the DM* is said? Because yes, DM always has the right to change things, but that can be assumed usually. Also, holding a spell with the Ready action is stated to require concentration, so point 2 can stand as is.

Comment: @BlakeSteel: It's stated right in the description of [Concentration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#Concentration): "The DM might also decide that certain environmental phenomena, such as a wave crashing over you while you're on a storm-tossed ship, require you to succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell." As for the other point, yes, Readying a spell or casting a spell with a casting time longer than 1 turn also requires concentration so the second bullet point covers that.

Comment: There are some other situations that end concentration. Entering Barbarian rage does it. There are also features other than spells that require concentration, like Draconic Presence and Visions of the Past. Some magic items also require concentration, for example marvellous pigments, ring of shooting stars.